# JHipster : how to customize bootstrap variables?

Tags: jhipster, bootstrap-4

I'm in a jhipster project using both Angular2 and bootstrap 4.
On the jhipster web site, there's a [page](http://www.jhipster.tech/customizing-bootstrap-4/) about how you can customize bootstrap variables, but I can't make this work with realtime changes.

When I put my customized variables in vendor.scss, if I want to see my changes, executing yarn run webpack:build:vendor is not enough, I need to rerun yarn start everytime....

How do I make so my changes are automatically applied ?

Comment: On which port do you test in browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize it in the vendor.scss file under the content folder

And make sure you are running the code on

localhost:9000 port.